# How do I reset a specific bone's "Stretch To" Rest Length, via code?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, bones, constraints

I'm trying to automate some processes. How do I "Reset" a "Stretch To" constraint in Blender, using python scripting. I copied the code that appeared in the "Info" window after executing the action manually. but when I used

```
bpy.ops.constraint.stretchto_reset(constraint="Stretch To", owner='BONE')
```

it does not work. Is there specific code references I need to import?
(I.E.: 
    import bpy,
    import mathutls
, etc.)
Or is there some qualifiers I need to add? Maybe about the specific bone? If so Where?

Signed, Greenhorn

Answer (score 2):

When running from the properties constraints panel context.constraint is defined.  To run in script elsewhere we need to [override context](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) ie add constraint to the context dictionary and pass it to the operator.

```
c = context.copy()  # copy the context returns dic.
# add constraint to the context dictionary
c["constraint"] = context.active_pose_bone.constraints['Stretch To']
# override context by passing dic as first argument
bpy.ops.constraint.stretchto_reset(c, constraint="Stretch To", owner='BONE')
```

Note: the code above is using the selected and active pose bone. There are numerous otherways to select and send a particular pose bone to the operator.