# How to use "Context Override" on the "Disable and Keep Transform" operator?

Tags: python, bones, constraints, operator, pose-mode

I am trying to make a simple panel with buttons for snapping bones between IK and FK configurations, and I need to change attributes of bone constraints with python scripting.

I can quite easily change something like the Influence of a constraint this way, however I am a little lost when it comes to executing/applying/pressing the Disable and Keep Transform button through script.

I found the operator: `bpy.ops.constraint.disable_keep_transform()`
and I know you should be able to use "Context Override" on the operator to feed it the appropriate context
*(found here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context)*

I have tried to copy "similiar" solutions from other people like in this question:
 [How do I reset a specific bone's "Stretch To" Rest Length, via code?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51117/how-do-i-reset-a-specific-bones-stretch-to-rest-length-via-code/51190)
but I havn't been able to find much information about how these operators and the "Context Override" works.

I feel like I am close.. but someone who knows how these operators work would be a big help.

**So the simple question:**
What context does the `disable_keep_transform()` operator need?

Comment: related: [poll() failed, context incorrect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

Comment: See first part of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172973/15543) which is pretty much disable constraint (set influence to zero) and keep transform.  Otherwise imagine that the operator override needs a "constraint" member which is present in PROPERTIES space but not elsewhere. Similarly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19602/child-of-constraint-set-inverse-with-python

Comment: So if I change the "area" attribute of the override context to one with a "PROPERTIES" type then it seems to work, however I'm currently just doing a for-loop to find the appropriate area, like this: 
`for area in bpy.context.screen.areas : if area.type == "PROPERTIES" : override["area"] = area`
.. Is there a better way of getting the correct area type for the override?